# Upgrade from Magento version from 2.4 to 2.4.1

Tags: magento2.4, magento2.4.1

I'm trying to update my magento 2.4 community edition to magento 2.4.1 executing the following commands:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.1 --no-update
composer update
```

I get the following error, can anyone help?
[image]

My composer.json looks as follows:

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "require": {
        "avada/module-proofo": "^1.0",
        "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~1.0",
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.0",
        "mageplaza/magento-2-portuguese-language-pack": "dev-master",
        "mageplaza/module-banner-slider": "^2.0",
        "mageplaza/module-customer-approval": "^1.0",
        "mageplaza/module-smtp": "^1.2",
        "olegkoval/magento2-regenerate-url-rewrites": "^1.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "~2.7.1",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.8.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "~5.0.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.3.1",
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.2.0"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "gene/bluefoot": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/",
                "generated/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "version": "2.3.1",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain packages

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition:2.4.1 paypal/module-braintree:2.4.2 --no-update
composer update
```

I think that should do it

Although interesting your composer version says 2.3.1

You might need to paste your lock

Answer (score 1):

First run this if you haven't

```
composer remove magento/product-community-edition --no-update
```